# JAXB update the XML file

Tags: jakarta-ee, jaxb

I'm using JAXB to generate XML file on the server. After the first time I deployed the server. I want to change some tag names of the XML file. Then I changed the some class variables. I recompiled the java files and redeploy. However, the XML do not change at all. Do I need to do some extra steps to update the XML file?

Comment: Show us the class' code and the code where you put those tags you mentioned. We cant anawer without that.

Answer (score 0):

By default JAXB (JSR-222) implemntations base the XML element names based on public properties (get/set methods) and public fields (instance variables).  If your fields were not public changing there name would not impact the XML tags.

If you want to base the element names on the fields you can use the `@XmlAccessorTypr(XmlAccessType.Field)` annotation:

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/06/using-jaxbs-xmlaccessortype-to.html

Also you can use `@XmlElement` on the property to change the name.